# References for Laplace Equation, weak solutions and eigenvalues via the variational method

Tags: partial-differential-equations, optimization, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, sobolev-spaces, laplacian

Could you point me towards books and/or papers which treat the weak form of Laplace (Poisson) equation and determine the eigenvalues and eigenfunctions of the Laplacian using the variational method (minimisation over the Sobolev space $ H_0^1$)?

Comment: Try J.Jost's PDE book (In GTM series)

Comment: Thank you, it has some of the variational approach to Laplace and Poisson equation but I couldn't find anything on the eigenvalues/functions of the Laplacian.

Comment: I vaguely remember that I found the construction in this book. I will check again.

Comment: Found, in p.229

Comment: Thank you, however page 229 contains the proof that $W^{1,2}$ is compactly embedded in $L^2$. I am reading from the third edition. Could you tell me which chapter and section?

Comment: It's section 8.5. The title is "Eigenvalues of Elliptic Operators". I was referring to the 2002 edition.

Comment: Thank you very much, it is section 11.5 in the third edition.